# Given a singly linked list, write a function to swap elements pairwise

Tags: c

I had to swap elements paiwise like following:

```
Eg: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 //Before
    2 14 3 6 5  8 7 //After
```

My swap function is as followes.

```
void swap(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p, *a, *q;
    p = head;
    do{
        head = p;
        p = head -> next -> next;
        q = head->next;               
        head -> next -> next = head;
        head -> next = p;
        head = q;
    } while(p!=NULL);
}
```

But the **code is not working**.
My full code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int dat;
    struct node *next;
};

void print(struct node *);
void swap(struct node *);

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct node *head, *h1, *h2, *h3, *h4, *h5, *h6, *h7, *h8;
    h1 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h2 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h3 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h4 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h5 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h6 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h7 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    h8 = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head = h1;
    h1 -> dat = 1;
    h1 -> next = h2;
    h2 -> dat = 2;
    h2 -> next = h3;
    h3 -> dat = 3;
    h3 -> next = h4;
    h4 -> dat = 4;
    h4 -> next = h5;
    h5 -> dat = 5;
    h5 -> next = h6;
    h6 -> dat = 6;
    h6 -> next = h7;
    h7 -> dat = 7;
    h7 -> next = h8;
    h8 -> dat = 8;
    h8 -> next = NULL;
    print(head);
    printf("\n\n");
    swap(head);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void print(struct node *head)
{
    if(head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", head -> dat);
        head = head -> next;
        print(head);
    }
}

void swap(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p, *a, *q;
    p = head;
    do{
        head = p;
        p = head -> next -> next;
        q = head -> next;               
        head -> next -> next = head;
        head -> next = p;
        head = q;
    } while(p != NULL);
}
```

Please help correct my code

Comment: Indent your code first!

Comment: How it is not working? Describe the expected and actual behavior.

Comment: That seems like a really, really odd implementation of swap. Wouldn't you want to pass it two pointers and have it swap their position in the list?

Comment: What are those hexBoxes at the top of the question?  Are they bananas or barteks?

Comment: Btw, what's that malloc for `head` followed by assignment to `head`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong in your code.
One is that you keep changing the head in the loop where you should only change it at the beginning (and use another variable when you traverse the linked-list). Also you should have more checks when you may hit the end of the list.

Try something like (disclaimer, I did not actually try it):

```
void swap(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *odd, *even;
    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
        return;
    odd = head;
    even = head->next;
    head = head->next;  // change this one once and for all

    while ((odd != NULL) && (even != NULL)) {
        // swap the elements
        odd->next = even->next;
        even->next = odd;

        // move to the next ones
        odd = even->next;
        if (odd != NULL)
            even = odd->next;
    }
}
```